# Is the recursion limit inclusive or exclusive and where do extra stack frames come from?

Tags: python, recursion

I have this recursive factorial function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Doing `factorial(998)` works, but `factorial(999)` will raise a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

Why does it error at `factorial(999)` and not `1000` or `1001`? `factorial(1)` hits the base case, so there should only be one stack frame from calling the `factorial` function, `factorial(2)` recurses once, so it should use 2 stack frames and so on.

Is the recursion limit exclusive or inclusive? As in, if you `setrecursionlimit(1000)` does it error when you *reach* 1000 stack frames or when you *exceed* 1000?

If it's exlusive, why does it error on `n=999` instead of `n=1000`? `n=999` should create 999 frames, not 1000. Where does the extra stack frame come from that makes it hit 1000? If the limit is inclusive, where do the extra 2 stack frames come from that make it hit 1001 stack frames?

Answer (score 3):

See for yourself. Python has great introspection tools:

```
import inspect

def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    print(len(inspect.stack()))
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Global level is already at 1-depth. First function call is 2-depth, so there's a one 'extra' stack frame in your calculations.

```
def f():
    print(len(inspect.stack()))

print(len(inspect.stack())) # 1
f() # 2
```

Comment: Yea, I did some experimenting and figured it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it?noredirect=1#comment104887028_3323001 but I was hoping someone could explain everything and give a certain answer.

Comment: Possibly even link to where this recursion limit check happens in the CPython source code. I think it's here [`(++tstate->recursion_depth > _Py_CheckRecursionLimit);`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51edf8aaa2e17626f9690ed29d25945fc03016b9/Include/cpython/ceval.h#L45) but that looks like it sould error when you *exceed* 1000, not when you hit 1000 stack frames. So is `recursion_depth` always 1 higher than it should be? Does the interpreter add another frame that doesn't appear in stack traces? Or am I missing some other context?

Comment: Err, the recursion limit check happens here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b08d3f71beab59653edfbbcf7b92a7bc8050d6b8/Python/ceval.c#L697 `tstate->recursion_depth > recursion_limit`